# Array value assigning switch returning the same value for all variables

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I m a hobbyist GameDev working on my first game, this is the first question I'm ever asking on this site.

Introductions aside here's my problem. My game is being designed for touchscreens, the player drags his finger through the screen and draws ramps that interact with the game.

The problem comes when I try to read the values in these ramps.

Every time the player drags his finger an array containing the most important values of the current movement (max, min, start, end etc) is passed. This array is recieved by an interpreter class that reads and process this data.

I'm having an issue with a method within the interpreter class, this method reads the array passed by the player drag and assigns a value to a series of arrays. The idea is to sort the different "ramps" so that I know witch info corresponds to each "ramp". This method uses a switch based on an int that tracks where the current drawing should be in the full drawing list.

The switch seems to be working well, I've tried putting counter values to test if the tracker is working fine and everything seems correct. However when I test my code it seems that all the different arrays are being assigned the same values every time I draw a new point. I'm I missing something?

Anyways sorry for the long text, here's my code:

```
Vector3[] PreviousRampDetails;
Vector3[] CurrentRampDetails;
Vector3[] NextRampDetails;
Vector3[] NextNextRampDetails;    

int ProcessedRamp;

GameObject PreviousRamp;
GameObject CurrentRamp;
GameObject NextRamp;
GameObject NextNextRamp;

//This method is called every time a new touch sequence begins
//The argument RampCreated corresponds with the object that is being generated along this sequence
void RampIdentifier(GameObject RampCreated)
{
    if (RampCreated == CurrentRamp)
    {
        ProcessedRamp = 0;
    }
    else if (ProcessedRamp == 0)
    {
        NextRamp = RampCreated;
        ProcessedRamp += 1;
    }
    else if (ProcessedRamp == 1 && NextRamp != RampCreated)
    {
        NextNextRamp = RampCreated;
        ProcessedRamp += 1;
    }
    else if (ProcessedRamp == 2 && NextNextRamp != RampCreated)
    {
        if (CurrentRamp != null)
        {
            NextNextRamp = RampCreated;
            CurrentRamp = null;
        }
        else
        {
            PreviousRamp = NextRamp;
            NextRamp = NextNextRamp;
            NextNextRamp = RampCreated;
        }
    }
}

//This method is called every time the player collides with a ramp.
//The argument ramp corresponds to the Object the player collides with.
void OnContactWithRamp(GameObject Ramp)
{
    CurrentRamp = Ramp;
    if (Ramp == NextRamp)
    {
        CurrentRampDetails = NextRampDetails;
        NextRamp = NextNextRamp;
        NextRampDetails = NextNextRampDetails;
        NextNextRamp = null;
        ProcessedRamp -= 1;
    }
    else if (Ramp == NextNextRamp)
    {
        CurrentRampDetails = NextNextRampDetails;
        NextRamp = PreviousRamp;
        PreviousRampDetails = NextRampDetails;
        NextNextRamp = null;
        ProcessedRamp = 0;
    }
    else if (Ramp == PreviousRamp)
    {
        CurrentRampDetails = PreviousRampDetails;
    }
}
```

And this is the bit that seems to be giving me trouble. I've tried isolating the variables so that their value is only assigned here but the problem persists:

```
//This method is called every time the player drags his finger through the screen
//The argument RampDetails contains the important information corresponding to the shape of the ramp that's being generated
void RampTracker(Vector3[] RampDetails) 
{
    switch (ProcessedRamp)
    {
        case 0:
            CurrentRampDetails = RampDetails;
            break;
        case 1:
            NextRampDetails = RampDetails;
            break;
        case 2:
            NextNextRampDetails = RampDetails;
            break;
    }
}
```

I've been banging my head against this for two days now and I can't find an answer to it. Thank you very much in advance!

---

Ok so I've tried handling this as Joe Blow said, and after some testing I've found that the error is somewhere in this code. The thing is that even if all the error messages are sent ("an error has happened somewhere" on the value assigner method) the values are still being changed to all be the same. This is the only part of the script where this values are set.

```
void RampValueAssigner(Vector3[] nprRDetails, Vector3[] ncRDetails, Vector3[] nnRDetails, Vector3[] nnnRDetails, int pR)
{
    if (pR == 1)
    {
        if (ncRDetails == nnRDetails || nnRDetails == nnnRDetails)
        {
            Debug.Log("an error has happened somewhere");
            return;
        }
        Debug.Log("No errors registered on PR 1");
        nextRampDetails = nnRDetails;
    }
    if (pR == 2)
    {
        if (ncRDetails == nnnRDetails || nnRDetails == nnnRDetails)
        {
            Debug.Log("an error has happened somewhere");
            return;
        }
        Debug.Log("No errors registered on PR 2");
        nextNextRampDetails = nnnRDetails;
    }
}

//Esta es la autentica ramp tracker
void RampTracker(Vector3[] rampDetails, int pRamp)
{
    Vector3[] a_previousRampDetails = previousRampDetails;
    Vector3[] a_currentRampDetails = currentRampDetails;
    Vector3[] a_nextRampDetails = nextRampDetails;
    Vector3[] a_nextNextRampDetails = nextNextRampDetails;

    if (pRamp == 0)
    {
        RampValueAssigner(a_previousRampDetails, rampDetails, a_nextRampDetails, a_nextNextRampDetails,0);
        return;
    } 
    if (pRamp == 1)
    {
        RampValueAssigner(a_previousRampDetails, a_currentRampDetails, rampDetails, a_nextNextRampDetails,1);
        return;
    }
    if (pRamp == 2)
    {
        RampValueAssigner(a_previousRampDetails, a_currentRampDetails, a_nextRampDetails, rampDetails,2);
        return;
    }

}
```

Comment: Check the values of the `NextRamp`, `NextNextRamp` etc at the end of each call to `RampIdentifier()`. I suspect that they are ending up all referencing the same object.

Comment: There is a Binary OPERATOR in your 4th else if -> &, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c.aspx, Is this really what you want?

Comment: Thanks for answering, I just checked, the values are being correctly assigned

Comment: Just edited and error on the last else if within the OnContactWithRamp() method, I was lacking an '=' in the operator. Sorry about that

Comment: YOU HAVE A TYPO `else if (ProcessedRamp == 2 & NextNextRamp != RampCreated)` IT SHOULD BE TWO AMPERSANDS - as Yosh explained.  Did you fix it or not?

Comment: Yes, just changed the code, both in my project and in the question. The issue persists

Comment: **DUDESTER!  VARIABLES *ARE LOWER CASE* LIKE thisWay NEVER LIKE ThisWay**.  It's very surprising you haven't picked this up yet as a keen hobbyist.  It will all have to be changed.  I'm writing you an answer.

Comment: So the lower case thing is why my variables are highlighted like classes... Okay, never again then, thank you...

Comment: No I'm not initializing the GameObjects, it doesn't give an error though, the values are being assigned correctly....

Comment: Are you familiar with using `Gizmo` in Unity?  to help, perhaps attach a gizmo ball (of different colors) to the three generations, and move it around when you change generations. it's almost impossible to unit-test this sort of thing unless you have "visual debugguing" you know?

Comment: Yes I've used before, but I didn't think about using in this context, I've used both Debug.Log and the inspector to test this

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up modifying the way the tracker works, now the processedRamp is modified by +1 every time the player **Lifts** his finger from the screen, this way I make sure its value remains the same throughout the entire touch routine.

On another hand I ended up fixing the error by assigning the values of the arrays this way:

```
void RampValueAssigner(Vector3[] nprRDetails, Vector3[] ncRDetails, Vector3[] nnRDetails, Vector3[] nnnRDetails, int pR)
{
    if (pR == 0)
    {
        if (ncRDetails == nnRDetails || ncRDetails == nnnRDetails)
        {
            return;
        }
        currentRampDetails = new Vector3[8] { ncRDetails[0], ncRDetails[1], ncRDetails[2], ncRDetails[3], ncRDetails[4], ncRDetails[5], ncRDetails[6], ncRDetails[7] };

    }
    if (pR == 1)
    {
        if (ncRDetails == nnRDetails || nnRDetails == nnnRDetails)
        {
            return;
        }
        nextRampDetails = new Vector3[8] { nnRDetails[0], nnRDetails[1], nnRDetails[2], nnRDetails[3], nnRDetails[4], nnRDetails[5], nnRDetails[6], nnRDetails[7] }; ;
    }
    if (pR >= 2)
    {
        if (ncRDetails == nnnRDetails || nnRDetails == nnnRDetails)
        {
            return;
        }
        nextNextRampDetails = new Vector3[8] { nnnRDetails[0], nnnRDetails[1], nnnRDetails[2], nnnRDetails[3], nnnRDetails[4], nnnRDetails[5], nnnRDetails[6], nnnRDetails[7] }; ;
    }
}
```

To be honest, I don't understand why this works and why the previous mehtod I was using (array = newarray) didn't. I'm glad I solved my problem, but I'd appreciate if someone could explain *how* did I do it.

Thank you very much!